# how to pull docker image on ECR using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I want to use docker image hosted on ECR and i want to automate the pull operation using cloudformation  template.

I attached IAM role with ECR full access to ec2 instance and it doesn't work.

i am doing `docker pull 1234567897.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repo:tag` and iam getting the error `Error response from daemon: Get https://1234567897.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repo:tag/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using ECR, EC2 and docker, you are still required to do a `docker login`.

In the user data run

`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email > login.sh`

`bash login.sh`

then you should be able to run

`docker pull ecr_registry/repo:tag`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_AWSCLI.html

Comment: The latest version of `aws` v2 does not have `get-login`: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a EC2 Instance running Windows then you need to run the powershell equivalent command of `aws ecr get-login` which is

```
Invoke-Expression –Command (Get-ECRLoginCommand –Region region).Command
```

Comment: This is working on windows, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, i will just add a one-liner example:

run:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
```

and then:

```
docker pull <ecr_host>/<repo>:<tag>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. If you add —region for those of us not in the US ;-) it works very well.

Comment: Because `$(command)` is cryptic and difficult to understand what it does